# Json On Complete Run Function

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a function run as soon as this json has fully completed and loaded. The problem I'm running into is that my links load before my anchors do. So it looks like everything has loaded but when you click on the links nothing loads until 3-6 seconds after you click because it is still loading the linked anchors. I'd love a way to definitively tell when this function has run and the content fully loaded. Anyone know how I might go about that?

I looked on Jquery's site and found something that might work but am unsure how to plug it in:

```
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Is this the right path and if so how might I get it to work with my code below:

```
<script>
        // ---------- AJAX JSON CALL ----------------
        $('.loading-wrapper').append('<div class="loading">Your page is loading…</div>');

        $.ajax({        
            url: "http://www.lcbcchurch.com/mobileJSON/gatherings",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                eventResults(data);
            }

        });

        function eventResults(data) {
            for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
            $("ul#"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"").append("<li><a id='video-"+data[i]["url_title"]+"' class='video-link' href='JavaScript:void(0);' >"+data[i]["title"]+"</a><div id='video-"+data[i]["url_title"]+"' class='video-thumb'>"+data[i]["embed-video"]+"</div></li>"); 
                if($("div.gathering").find("#"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"").length == 0){
                        $("body").prepend("<div id='"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"div' class='event-detail' data-role='page'><div id='back"+data[i]["url_title"]+"' class='back-header' data-role='header'><a href='series.html' data-icon='delete' iconpos='notext' id='close'>Cancel</a><h1></h1></div><img src='"+data[i]["categories"][0]["series-small-image"]+"'/><div class='campus-page'>"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_description"]+"<ul id='"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"'></ul></div></div>");
                        $(".gathering").append("<a href='#"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"div' class='cat-link' id='"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"' rel='external' onClick='picsHide();'><img src='"+data[i]["categories"][0]["series-small-image"]+"' width='156' height='74'/></a>");
                }
        }
        $('.loading-wrapper').empty();
        $('.inline-scripts').append("<script src='scripts/inline.js'><\/script>");

        if($("div.gathering").find("#"+data[i]["categories"][0]["category_id"]+"").length == 0){

        // Call the pics ready function     
        }
    </script>
```

- IOS Phonegap app
- JQUERY 1.7.1
- Jquery-Mobile 1.1

Comment: I definitely thing you would be well served to look at making a template, instead of creating the HTML straight in JavaScript.

Comment: Why not add the alert after the eventResults() method is called in your ajax success handler? 
`success:function(data){
                eventResults(data); alert('Done!');

            }`

Comment: Hey Tejs - Sorry for the ignorance but what do you mean by a template? Could you link me to a template setup tutorial you're talking about. I'm struggling with load times on my app, so if the template system could help with that, I'm all ears!

Comment: Hey Jason, that works as well but the problem is getting to alert me that the html elements have loaded as well, not just that the script ran. Make sense? What it ends up doing is alerting me as soon as the script runs but then the html elements slowly load after it alerts me.

Comment: @nate Perhaps this answer would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775259/ensuring-load-code-fires-in-jquery-event-if-attaching-event-after-load-occurs